# What does this sign/element from a circuit diagram mean?

Tags: circuit-design, schematics

Can someone help me understand what the V/2 element/sign means and how I should connect it?

I have highlighted them in red.

[image]

Comment: It means that all of this points are connected to the half of a supply voltage V/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a node with half supply voltage.

They are same node so they are really connected together.

Same thing like with the V+ symbols of the op-amp are the supply voltage that are connected together and coming from supply.

Comment: You might want to explain why. This is a single-supply circuit instead of a bipolar supply and they need a "mid-point" that would otherwise be missing. Stuff like that, I mean. It's often helpful to provide those clues as the OP may not follow why things are as they are here. It's not painful and it provides a centering context out of which understanding flows.